# How to pass generic for React.FC?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I want to define a Component like:

```
type CompPropsType = {
  // some fields
}

export const Comp: React.FC<CompPropsType> = () => {
  return <h1>hello</h1>
}
```

and then, `CompPropsType` has changed to :

```
type CompPropsType2<T> = {
  // some fields
  fieldOne: T[]
  callbackTwo: (data: T[]) => void
}

export const Comp2: React.FC<CompPropsType2<T>> = (props) => {
  const handleClick = () => {
    // some code ...
    const data = [] as T[] // data generated by other code
    props.callbackTwo(data)
  }

  return <h1 onClick={handleClick}>hello</h1>
}
```

now, how should i define `"T"` for CompPropsType2 ?

Comment: It is impossible to infer props generic and at the same time use `React.FC`. Please consider [this example](https://tsplay.dev/NB5qzw)

Comment: It can solve the problems of props, but in this way, Comp2 can not get static fields defined on React.FC

Comment: what type you want to set to fieldOne

Comment: passed by the caller of Comp2 , may string number or string[] and so on

Comment: if it can be any type that caller can assign it should be `any` or `unknown` . if it can be one of some specific types it should be `string | number | string[]`. i don't understand why you are using generic types here

Comment: In my case, fieldOne may be an object array whose type is determined by the caller. I don't know which fields there are, so I can't simply specify string number or any

Comment: I updated the example in the question. In the new code, when the title was clicked, the callback function passed in by the caller will be called, and the generic type array specified by the caller will be passed in